# How do you make a character navigate along a grid in the BGE?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I am currently developing a concept of a game, and a critical part is the character navigation. The game is based on a 2D grid, and I need to be able to navigate **one block at a time**, **in only straight lines**.

If it makes it easier, the scaling is non-critical, so grid blocks can be one Blender unit.

Answer (score 2):

Your request is pretty simple.

Limit any movement to:

- 90 degree turns
- steps of 1 BU size
- do not use the physics engine

This assumes you want to move in discrete steps (in frame t the object is at A and in frame t+1 the object is at B without any intermediate steps).

Answer (score 1):

The Game Engine is by default a 3D rigid body simulator, so such constraints, like forcing objects to grid positions and limiting movement to one unit along one axis at a time, will have to be programmed with the Logic Editor and Python scripts. Basically you will have to program a different game engine for your 2D game inside Blender. If you are lucky you will find libraries and modules for a 2D grid-based game to help you make this.

Some quick notes for the engine:

- Game objects will have "moving" and "waiting" states.
- In "moving" state the object is not on a grid point, but moving/animating between two points. The object will store the earlier point and the destination, and a timer value. These three are used to visually animate the movement by interpolating the object position.
- In "waiting" state the object is sitting on a grid point, and waiting for an event. For the object controlled by the player, that event is player input. For computer controlled objects, that's either a timeout used for making the opponent less speedy, or if that time's up then calculate the next destination and start moving towards that.